# Getting the HttpResponseMessage Content value which is set manually(hard coded in the code)

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I have a method in my application where I have to set the `HttpResponseMessage` response for some reason. This is my below code I have. There is class Order and OrderDetail.

```
         public void someMethod()
        {
            var response = await SendHttpResponse("123");
            Order objId = new Order();
            objId = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).ToObject<Order>();
            string item = objId.OrderDetail.LastOrDefault<item>().Status

        }
```

SendHttpResponse method, where the HttpResponseMessage is hardcoded.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendHttpResponse(string orderid)
{
    Task<Order> result = CreateOrder(orderid);
    string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    { Content = new StringContent(jsonString) };// assuming something wrong with this conversion
}
```

I have an `Order` class and `OrderDetail` class.

```
public async Task<Order> CreateOrder(string OrderId)
{
    Order order = new Order();
    order.id = OrderId;
    order.date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    OrderDetail od = new OrderDetail();
    od.item = "xyz";
    od.rate = 12;
    List<OrderDetail> lst = new List<OrderDetail>();
    lst.Add(od);
    order.OrderDetail = lst;
}
```

Now the problem I'm facing is, in SomeMethod, `item` is coming as null instead of  `xyz`. When I debug this, I can see that CreateOrder method is executed without any exception and data is also converted to JSON format, but those values are not returned to `SomeMethod` properly.  I'm assuming, the conversion I'm doing in `SendHttpResponse` is wrong and should be done differently.

Can any help me to correct this code? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateOrder(orderid);` returns a `Task`, not the `Order` object.

So you have to `await` it.

```
Order result = await CreateOrder(orderid); //
```

you also forget to return the order in the CreateOrder method.

you also forget to add `async` to `public void someMethod()`.

So your code should not be compiled successfully.

Comment: and change someMethod to return `Task` instead of `void`, even if it's not strictly necessary. `async void` methods should be used only as event handlers

Comment: When i change CreateOrder to await CreateOrder, it is giving a compilation error "Cannot convert Namespace.Order to System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Namespace.Order> "

Comment: Change the whole line as I wrote. Not just add an await.